# raise NeedDownloadError('Need ffmpeg exe. ' NeedDownloadError: Need ffmpeg exe)

Tags: python, python-2.7, instagram-api

Estoy tratando de ejecutar una API de Instagram no oficial escrita en Python, después de varios errores de dependencias necesarias arreglados estoy trabado en este error:

```
File "C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\txts_pys_phps_programacion\Instagram-API-python-master\InstagramAPI.py", line 15, in <module>
    from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\moviepy\editor.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\VideoFileClip.py", line 3, in <module>
    from moviepy.video.VideoClip import VideoClip
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\VideoClip.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .io.ffmpeg_writer import ffmpeg_write_image, ffmpeg_write_video
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_writer.py", line 15, in <module>
    from moviepy.config import get_setting
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\moviepy\config.py", line 38, in <module>
    FFMPEG_BINARY = get_exe()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\imageio\plugins\ffmpeg.py", line 86, in get_exe
    raise NeedDownloadError('Need ffmpeg exe. '
NeedDownloadError: Need ffmpeg exe. You can download it by calling:
  imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este error es bastante explicativo:

```
`NeedDownloadError: Need ffmpeg exe. You can download it by calling:`
```

El script está requiriendo la herramienta ffmpeg.exe. La puedes descargar desde [aquí](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/), presta atención a la arquitectura. Obviamente el EXE debiera estar en el PATH.

Asimismo, como variante, el error está recomendando: `You can download it by calling:
  imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()` lo cual significa que también podrías hacer esto desde el script python:

```
import imageio 
imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()
```